# Find all answers to $3x^{10}=10x^3\pmod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Number theory related question.

Give all answers to:

$$3x^{10}\equiv 10x^3 \pmod{13}$$

$0$ is obvious but I can't see a good way to draw out $12$.

I've got this so far:

Rearrange to $3x^{10}-10x^3\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$

Factor out $x^3$, to give:

$x^3(3x^7-10)\equiv 0\pmod{13}$

$0$ works because of $x^3$ term

I'm still looking for:

$(3x^7-10)\equiv 0\pmod{13}$

Is there an easy way to find this?

And if I get an answer to this, am I okay to assume there are no other answers between $0$ and $13$?

Comment: How about using the fact that $-10 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$?

Comment: So 3x^7=10(mod13),3x^7=-3(mod13), x^7=-1(mod13), x=-1(mod13), x=12

Comment: Is that ok and also am I now all right to assume there are no other answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3x^{10}\mod{13}=10x^3\mod{13}$

$-10x^{10}\mod{13}=10x^3\mod{13}$

$10(x^3+x^{10})\mod{13}=0\mod{13}$ This means:$\ $
$-x^3\mod{13}=x^{10}\mod{13}$

Comment: Great! Really helpful, thank you.

Comment: Why is it true that $-x^3\equiv x^{10}\pmod {13}$? Is there an obvious reason or was this left for the OP to further prove somehow?

Comment: @mathh This was indeed something for the OP (original poster?) to solve...

Comment: @Aal Which way of proving it do you think is the best one?

Comment: @Aal Could you tell me the way you've used to prove $-x^3\equiv x^{10}\pmod {13}$? I mean, I could split it into cases... When $13 \not\mid x$, we can prove that $x^7\equiv -1\pmod {13}$. Otherwise there's nothing to prove. So I could check the remainders $x^7$ can get when divided by $13$, but is there a more elegant way? This one is a bit tedious imho.

Comment: @mathh I've just computed them by hand. This is actually only half as tedious as it looks, because once you`ve computed $1^7$ to $6^7$ you only have to negate these results (why?). And by "smart" calculating you can do this very easily by hand.

Comment: @Aal I knew I could do it this way, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution. I do know that, e.g., $3^7\equiv -6^7\pmod {13}$.